# Is it possible to update Azure DevOps organization name programmatically?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a question. Currently, I am attempting to rename Azure DevOps project and organization names using the REST API. I have found the API for the project update - [Update project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1), but I cannot find any documentation on how to update an organization. So my question is: Is there a way to programmatically update a DevOps organization name, either through an API or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the Organization name, you can do it from the Azure DevOps console with some [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/rename-organization?view=azure-devops#prerequisites) and there is also a REST API available but I haven't tested it out if you can rename the Organization with it.

[Rename your organization in Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/rename-organization?view=azure-devops)

[Organizations - Update (REST API)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/2022-10-31-previewdataplane/organizations/update?tabs=HTTP)